# Enable scroll bar on fixed window border div

Tags: css, fixed

I'm trying to enable browser scroll bar in my website but didn't work.

This is the site online : http://guillaumeruiz.com

All projects in this "gallery" are hidden and visible with a hide Id function. I used a left-right-top-bottom fixed divs for the red window border. And, every div project have a fixed position too to cover the main gallery.

If you can help me please... thank you

Comment: The scrollbar is there, but it's hidden by your `<div id="right"></div>`.

Comment: good point, <div id="right"></div> should be align considering scroll bar, but ...nayway... right now if you remove id="right" scrollbar does not appear anyway

Comment: Yes there is something missing anywhere ... I'm looking to grow up the scroll bar with z-index if it's possible ...